# change return from shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: at runTime

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm using  shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: for respond YES to all orientations.

At runtime, in few case, i must change the return to YES only in portrait.

But if i change this return type, and my device not physicly turn, my interface orientation not change.
How can it's possible to force uiView to check the  shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: and rotate the view without UIdevice rotation notification.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this two lines of code:

```
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Answer (score 1):

Static method starting from IOS 5: 
`[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];`