# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: never called

Tags: ios, iphone, orientation

I set supported Interface Orientations to be all except Portrait upside down under Deployment Info.

I would like to override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: for custom behaviour. (i.e support landscape as per condition)

I only have one viewcontroller due to constraints(customized view transitions)

this is what the code in my appdelegate looks like:

```
self.viewController = [[MyController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

and in myController.m, i override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

the application autorotates to all orientations but portrait upside down and the call back is never called. I have tried the suggestion at [change return from shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: at runTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518961/change-return-from-shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-at-runtime) with no success. why?

on a side note, what would be the best way to change rotation support at runtime?

**update:**

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

gets called. I tried placing in

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

with no success :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

was using ios6

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
```

is deprecated on ios6

Comment: Yes. Override the supportedInterfaceOrientations and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation methods instead.

Answer (score 1):

Its Working for me:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    if ([self isKindOfClass:[YourViewController class]]) { // Your view class
        orientations |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
    }
    return orientations;
}
```

orientations:

```
orientations |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
orientations |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
```