# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation doesn't work in ios6 simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, ios-simulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105085/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation-never-called)

I have application uses some orientations but the problem is when i rotate the ios6 simulator to left or right the

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 return YES;
}
```

does not even called !!! , while when i used the ios 5.1 simulator it called and it works fine ? any help will be appreciated,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is deprecated in `iOS 6.0`. Override the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` methods instead.